# Running two mySql queries to get data

Tags: php, mysql

I want to run 2 query on two tables under 1 database in PHP.
1st table name is users_account and
the other is friends. And I am using database class and prepare statement for this.

```
$me = $_COOKIE['current_user'];
```

**1st query**

```
$query = "select * from friends where (sender = '$me' || reciever = '$me')";
$result = $DB->read($query);
If($result){
    foreach($result as $row){
    
    }
}
```

I'm getting more than 1 rows in object formation.
Now I'm trying to run another query by this row's either sender or reciever.

**2nd Query**

```
$sql = "select * from users_account where authentication != $row->sender || authentication != $row->reciever";

$result2 = $DB->read($sql);
If($result2){
    echo $result2;
}
```

But the problem is that I'm getting the 2nd query's result by the last row of 1st query. I'm not getting all the result.
How can I get all the result.

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you executing that second query - inside the foreach loop, or …?

Comment: And why does a `friends` table have a `sender` and `receiver` column to begin with? What does users being friends, have to do with “sending” and “receiving”? Presumably your `friends` table should rather be called `messages` or something like that …?

Comment: I have tried both inside and outside the foreach.but I can't get  the result that I want

Comment: I'm trying to show suggested friends like facebook and not to show friend requested user that I have sent.

Comment: You either need to do it inside the loop, so that you perform one query for each record you read from your `friends` table, or create one query that has the senders and receivers wrapped into `IN(…)` operators. Also possible that your data could be JOINed together in one single query, but you have not given us enough information about your data model so far to be able to tell.

Comment: No. This is a place to discuss your question in public, so please don’t try and use it to solicit private support/tutoring. This is a Q&A site, so ideally future readers with similar problems, should be able to benefit from your question as well. So explain the necessary details directly in your question.

Comment: Ok.If I run the query inside the loop,  I get different results for each query. I need 1 result

Comment: Then put them into an array, instead of echo-ing them inside the loop.

Comment: I think your query is wide open to SQL injection.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

$sql = "select * from users_account where (authentication != $row->sender) || (authentication != $row->receiver)";

Comment: Tried this one.